# Excel -Looking to use VBA to build a table of contents with extra cells copied

Tags: excel, vba

I have a good basic script that returns me the sheet name of each sheet in the workbook, but now I'd like to add the contents of cell A1, A2, A3, and A4 into columns B, C, D, and E and add a header row with "Link, Variable, Definition, Calculation, Notes" in columns A, B, C, D. The existing hyperlink will be in column A.

It will need to loop through the entire workbook, and if possible skip adding a link to the table of contents page. Here is a basic script I currently use (borrowed from Extend Office) -

```
'updateby Extendoffice 20180413
    Dim xAlerts As Boolean
    Dim I  As Long
    Dim xShtIndex As Worksheet
    Dim xSht As Variant
    xAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Table of contents").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xShtIndex = Sheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    xShtIndex.Name = "Table of contents"
    I = 1
    Cells(1, 1).Value = "Table of contents"
    For Each xSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        If xSht.Name <> "Table of contents" Then
            I = I + 1
            xShtIndex.Hyperlinks.Add Cells(I, 1), "", "'" & xSht.Name & "'!A1", , xSht.Name
        End If
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = xAlerts
End Sub
```

Comment: @bigBen - I tried that and it worked for my first line but the breaks must have messed it up some how.

Comment: @BigBen - I think it was the hard return, thanks for the input.

Comment: So, what exactly is the issue with your code?

Comment: There is no issue, I am trying to add additional functionality to the code. I tried to spell it out in detail in the post. I have 4 cells of data in each sheet I want to append to my table of contents.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if this does exactly what you want, there is some gaps in the explanation in regards how you want to handle the link fucntion. Since you mention the code "works" but you want some added function, and you dont want links on the "table of contents" but it doesn't do that now either?

anyway give this a go...

```
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    
    Dim xAlerts As Boolean
    Dim I  As Long
    Dim xShtIndex As Worksheet
    Dim Table As Worksheet
    Dim xSht As Variant
    xAlerts = Application.DisplayAlerts
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False
    On Error Resume Next
    Sheets("Table of contents").Delete
    On Error GoTo 0
    Set xShtIndex = Sheets.Add(Sheets(1))
    xShtIndex.Name = "Table of contents"
    Set Table = Worksheets("Table of contents")
    I = 2
    targetcolumn = 1
    'Cells(1, 1).Value = "Table of contents"
    'Disabled this because i'm not sure if this code should be here?
    For Each xSht In ThisWorkbook.Sheets
        With xSht
            If xSht.Name = "Table of contents" Then
                .Cells(1, 1).Value = "Table of contents"
                .Range("A1").Value = "Link"
                .Range("B1").Value = "Variable"
                .Range("C1").Value = "Definition"
                .Range("D1").Value = "Calculation"
                .Range("E1").Value = "Notes"
            End If
            
            If xSht.Name <> "Table of contents" Then
                    lrow = .Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row
                    Dim copyrng As Range
                    Set copyrng = .Range("A1:A" & lrow)
                    copycount = 2 'skipping one because with 1 it would write to row 1 which is where the headers are
                    For Each cell In copyrng
                        Table.Cells(targetcolumn, copycount).Value = cell.Value
                    copycount = copycount + 1
                    Next
                Table.Hyperlinks.Add Table.Cells(I, 1), "", "'" & xSht.Name & "'!A1", , xSht.Name
                I = I + 1

            End If

        End With
        targetcolumn = targetcolumn + 1
    Next
    Application.DisplayAlerts = xAlerts
End Sub
```

Comment: Hey there, This adds the hyperlink to column A in the table of contents sheet which is expected behavior, but then it overwrites the first four columns in each sheet. My expected outcome is to leave each of the sheets alone other than copying A1, A2, A3, and A4 into the table of contents page columns B, C, D, E. I really appreciate this, it's very close.

Comment: Ohh, this wasn't clear to me but i'm gathering now that your "Table of contents" is your first of five Tabs? In a workbook where this page isn't there yet, this would be added as a new tab which is why that part of the problem didn't exist for me.

as far as the other part, ill adjust the code in a bit for you.

Comment: The table of contents is my first worksheet. And unfortunately this workbook is a bit of a pig, it has 137 sheets not including the table of contents. The current macro either creates the TOC if it doesn't exist, or over writes it if it does. I'm hoping to add those cells from each sheet to the columns of the table of contents. They basically describe what is in each sheet. The final TOC will have like 138 rows with 5 columns.

Comment: Updated the code above, give it another go..

i did disable code for putting the value "Table of contents" as it was eithe overwritten by the header "links" in the table of contents, or it would replace the "A1" range in your Sheet2.

Comment: Thanks my friend. I stepped out for a bit. I'll be back at it in a few hours and I'll let you know. Thanks for your level of effort.

Comment: Dude - all I can say is you rock - this does exactly what I need. Many thanks.

Comment: Is there a way to mark the solution as verified or solved?